# Stability of a Specific Hill's Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

**Consider the Hill's Equation $u''+a(t)u=0$ where $a(t)=a(t+T)$ for all $t$.
Show that if $a(t)<0$ for all $t$, then the solution satisfying the inital condition $u(0)=u'(0)=1$ is unbounded as $t \rightarrow \infty$. Hence deduce that this solution describes behavior.**

So I was given a hint to try to go about this by using the expression $u'=1-\int^t_0a(s)u(s) ds$

I figured, that if I can use this to show that $u'(t) \geq 1$ for $t \geq 0$, then that should be sufficient, but after playing around with the expression above I haven't been able to make any progress, so if at the very least I could get a few steps in the right direction that would be most helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $t_0$ is the least $t > 0$ such that $u'(t) \le 1/2$, then $u(s) \ge 1 + s/2$ for
$0 \le s \le t_0$, so ...

Comment: So this is supposed to show that since $a(s)$ is always negative over the interval and $u(s)$ is positive over the sub-interval that the integral should have a negative value (or 0) and thus $u'$ should always be positive?

Even if that is the incorrect assumption, how are we sure that $u'(t)$ has a value $t_0$ that satisfies the inequality $u'(t)\leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: The point is that it doesn't.  This is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand yet (I know what proof by contradiction is and whatnot) and I don't see how this uses any of the properties of the problem, but I will continue to think about it to make a connection. Thanks.